# Poster or Map Presentation Guidelines?

Tags: paper, cartography

Is there a website that will guide me through for various kind of paper size to create a/ or several presentation for digital or hardcopy maps/ or poster with different fonts, display area, title and so on. I am more interesting in reading on what is the recommend for the font size and the paper size.

Comment: Can you make this more specific to cartography/GIS? There's a [similar question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/what-are-some-general-good-principles-for-creating-a-poster-for-a-poster-session/2337#2337) with some good answers on Academia.SE.

Comment: Actually what I am trying to say here is if you have a map that is in 60 x 34 paper size. What the font size should be, the Title size should be and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I have not gotten any answered on this my questions. I found several that might be a good example to share.

http://gis.joewheaton.org/assignments/project/poster-session

http://www.ncsu.edu/project/posters/index.html

http://www.kumc.edu/SAH/OTEd/jradel/Poster_Presentations/PstrStart.html